# React array defined with useState is not updated after trying to acces the variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mouseevent, mousemove

Im trying to make a calendar widget where you can click and create an event at a certain starttime, if you hold mouse down and move down, the event becomes bigger (endtime gets later). Which works in the frontend, but i'm not able to acces the event i just created in my events state.

I useState for const array of events. On mouseDown i create an event and update the events' state. Which works. On mouseMove i update the events state again by finding the event for it's key in the prevState of the events array. Which also works.
But on mouseUp i want to find the event for it's key again to return the object i just created. But my events state does not contain the event i created on the screen. This time i just want to use the already created eventObject in another function, not update it. Howcome this event is not available in my events state on mouseUp, while it was already available in my mouseMove part. It probably has someting todo with that i'm accessing events from prevState in the mousemove and im not doing that in mouseUp. But how do you acces the most recent state when you don't want to update the state at that moment? (see comments added to code).

```js
const [key, setKey] = useState(1000);


// creating state of array of events here.
const [events, setEvents] = useState(null)

const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log("HandleClick...");

        const eventsSameDateTime = events.filter(
            ev =>  {
            const sameGridRow =  ev.gridRowStart === getRowForEvent(e);
            const sameGridColum = ev.gridcolumn === getColumnForEvent(e);;
            return sameGridRow && sameGridColum}
        );
        
        const count = eventsSameDateTime.length+1;
        newEvent = {
            date: null, 
            gridRowStart: getRowForEvent(e), 
            gridRowEnd: getRowForEvent(e)+4, 
            gridcolumn: getColumnForEvent(e), 
            title: "new", 
            createDate: new Date(),   
            zIndex: count,    
        };
        
        const newEvents = [...eventsSameDateTime, newEvent]
        .sort((a, b) => a.createDate.getTime() - b.createDate.getTime())
        .map((ev, i) => {
            const newKey = key+i;
            ev.key = newKey;
            setKey(prevState => prevState+i)
            ev.zIndex = i + 1;
            ev.otherEvents = count;
            return ev;
        })
        
        // updating the events state here onclick (initial creation)
        setEvents((prevState) => {
            const oldEvents = prevState.filter(pEv => newEvents.find(nEv => nEv.key === pEv.key) == null);
            return [...oldEvents, ...newEvents];
        })
    }

    const handleMouseDown = (e1) => {
        console.log("HandleMouseDown...");
        if (e1.target.className.includes("event-container")) {
            setKey(prevState => {
                console.log(`updating key onClick...`);
                return prevState+1;
            });
            e1.preventDefault();
            handleClick(e1);

            const handleMouseMove = (e2) => {
                console.log("HandleMouseMove...")
                e2.preventDefault();
                
                // updating the events array state on mousemove.(one event endstime in the array)
                setEvents((prevState) => {
                    console.log(`updating events onMove...`);
                    
                    // the event i created on click is available in the prevState.
                    console.log("events on mouseMove: ", prevState);
                    return [...prevState].map((ev) => {
                        if (ev.key === newEvent.key) {
                            ev.gridRowEnd = getRowForEvent(e2)
                        }
                        return ev;
                    })
                })  
            }
            e1.target.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

            const handleMouseUp = (e3) => {
                e3.preventDefault();
                console.log("HandleMouseUP");

                const removeMouseMoveAndDown = (e) => {
                    e.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
                    e.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
                }             

                if (isEvent(e1.target)) { 
                    console.log("Removing Event mouseUpDown");
                    removeMouseMoveAndDown(e1.target);
                }
                const eventContainer = findWeekElement(e1.target);
                console.log("Removing EventContainer mouseUpDown");
                removeMouseMoveAndDown(eventContainer);
                
                // when i log the events array, the event i created onclick is not in there.
                console.log("events on mouseUp: ", events);
                const existingEvent = events.find(ev => ev.index === key);
                props.payload.setValue(JSON.stringify(createUiEventForEvent(existingEvent)));
                props.eventActions.onCreate();
            }
            e1.target.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp); 
        } else {
            console.log("nothing happens, you probably clicked an event");
        }
    }
```

Comment: edit: the topcode of the snippet should have a "let newEvent = null';"

Comment: Please provide a working example so we can see the complete usage.